# Sharepoint Datasheet Compact view

Tags: sharepoint-online, datasheet, multiple-lines-of-text

Can we make Datasheet view like wrap-text we do in excel current column have large multiple text which is making hard to read or edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Read in List View**:

In SharePoint Online Modern experience List, it automatically wraps the text in multiple lines of text column in **List View** like below:

[image]

**To Edit in Quick Edit Mode**:

However in Quick edit mode, you can change the width of column to wrap the text at some point like given in below image. But there is no OOTB way to change the height of row:

[image]

Comment: its useful but height is lso need to be fix for row let me check alternative

Comment: Sure, Maybe you can try adding some CSS/JS as you are already familiar with modern script editor (Not recommended though).

Comment: i am using classic experience there i can add script let me check which css need to be alter